# Can a company restrict an employee from looking for a job while they are on a PIP?

Tags: disability

Can a company or employer restrict a person from looking for a job while he/she is put on a PIP?

Comment: Do you mean looking for another job while you're on duty for the current job? Or looking after hours, on your days off, etc.?

Comment: You need to provide more information. What does your contract say, what is your location, do you look for jobs on company time or your own time? As the question stands, it is not clear what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: How does the disability tag tie into your question?

Comment: A PIP cannot restrict you from doing anything outside of the time you are being paid by the company you currently work for. So, if they try adding a line in the PIP restricting your non-work activities, they are stepping out of their "jurisdiction". If your currently employer states that you cannot use company resources (computer, iPad, phone, etc) or while during work hours, they are within their rights. Were you job searching while on the clock? If so, they probably noted it when reviewing your computer activity and decided it needed to be said.

Answer (score 3):

A PIP is usually a preparation to fire you. So think about it: If you are on a PIP, and you look for and find another job, what's the worst that can happen? They fire you (however, firing you for looking for another job would be something that might be used against them), which they wanted anyway.

Most likely the company is only too happy if you find a job elsewhere and leave on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your contract says otherwise, you can always look for another job ,-- on your own time, of course, and subject to any  non-compete clauses in that contract

Comment: You can always look for another job on your own time, REGARDLESS of what your contract says. This is especially true for PIP's which are widely regarded as a code-word for "you're going to be fired, look for another job."